# Hide URL Segments But Want To Access These Segments In Controller Method In PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Want To Hide URL Last Two Segments But Want To Access These Hidden Segments In controller Method In PHP Codeigniter.
This Is What I Currently Have

somewebsite/somemethod/dragonhunter2009720pblurayx264ytsag-greek/2/11
and accessing as

```
$this->uri->segment('3');
$this->uri->segment('4');
```

This Is What I Want To Have

```
somewebsite/somemethod/dragonhunter2009720pblurayx264ytsag-greek
```

But I Want To Access These Two Hidden Segment Values In Controller Method

as

```
$this->uri->segment('3');
$this->uri->segment('4');
```

How Can I Do This...

Comment: what is the reason behind such an idea ? i can't think of any task which requires this kind of implementation...

Answer (score 0):

URLs do not provide any functionality to send "hidden" data. Therefore you cant hide the values in your url.

However you could use a middle class controller which redirects the user one extra time:

**1.** User makes request for `/subtitles/xy/1/2` Request is answered by the following function:

```
public function middleware(){
  $this->load->library('session');
  //Local variables just for easier understanding
  $seg2 = $this->uri->segment('2');
  $seg3 = $this->uri->segment('3');
  $seg4 = $this->uri->segment('4');

  //Store the data in a session
  $this->session->set_userdata('seg3', $seg3);
  $this->session->set_userdata('seg4', $seg4);
  redirect('subtitles/'.$seg2);
}
```

**2.** Codeigniter sets the session variables and redirects the user to another function which retrieves the values

```
public function handleSubtitles(){
  $this->load->library('session');
  //Retrieve the values from the session library 
  $seg3 = $this->session->userdata('seg3');
  $seg4 = $this->session->userdata('seg4');
  //Unset the values 
  $this->session->unset_userdata('seg3');
  $this->session->unset_userdata('seg4');}
}
```

In order for this to work, you need to adjust your routing configuration too: `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['subtitles/(:any)'] = "subtitles/handleSubtitles";
$route['subtitles/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "subtitles/middleware";
```

However I would just leave the to values in the URL... It'll make your work easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do dynamic routing for each subtitle in your CI's routing. For doing this, open your routes.php (application/config/routes.php) and write below code:-

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB.php' );

$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get('subtitles');   // select the table which have the data and url slug
$result = $query->result();
foreach($result as $r) { 

    $route['subtitles/'.$r->url_slug] = "subtitles_controller/{$r->url_slug}/{$r->id1}/{$r->id2}";  
 }
```

// Hint for above code : -

  1. $r->url_slug :- use your table name for the slug .

  2. $r->id1 and  $r->id2 :- use your table name for both the ids .

  3. subtitles_controller  :- use the correct controller name from your application to where you want to route .

You can also rout even without any controller name in the beginning (without "subtitles"). For doing this, you can remove the **subtitles** from the beginning of routing.

```
eg: $route[$r->url_slug] = "subtitles/{$r->url_slug}/{$r->id1}/{$r->id2}";
```

now on your controller subtitles

```
function subtitles_controller($slug,$id1,$id2)
     // here you can access the variables 
}
```